# Howto implement a global "Instant search" in a windows 8 metro app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

**Hello Community,**

I'm new in programming Win8-Metro e.g. Win8-Store Apps (C# Way) and I'm trying to program a global instant search via the search contract (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465231.aspx).

The instant search like I want to implement, is exactly like the search for "Apps"/"App search". Every keyboard entry bring up new found applications in the search window (no suggestions below the search charm textbox), without pressing enter.

In normal case you have to implement the LoadState and Filer_SelectionChanged events in the "Search Results Page". I want the same behaviour like searching in "Apps" (I know that there is no search history!).

How could that be implemented? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using the search contract:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5

Comment: Hi and thanks fo your answer, but this is not an answer to my question. I know this sample but it didn't show how to create an instant search!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  By Instant search, do you mean that the results are shown as you type?  If that is what you mean, I suggest you look into the OnSuggestionsRequested event.

for example...

```
private void OnSuggestionsRequested(SearchPane sender, SearchPaneSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    string query = args.QueryText;
    string[] terms = { "an item", "Oscillator", "crossbeam", "treddle", "Interossitor", "Spline", "Flange" };

    foreach (var term in terms)
    {
        if (term.StartsWith(query, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            args.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion(term);
        }
    }
}
```

This method will bring you back a list of potential matches from your app when the user starts to type.  The suggestions will be listed below the search box on the Search charm.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. But this is not the solution. To get things right: The search results should be shown on keypress but "not" as suggestions below the search charm textbox! It should work like the "App Search". Results are shown in the search window ...

Comment: In that case, what you want is not possible, I'm afraid.  The search charm is handled by the system, not your application.  It simply makes a call into your application at specific points in the process - as you type it will request suggestions, and on hitting enter it will launch your app.  No way around that that I know of I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi, I'm working currently on a solution by manually handling the Searchpane.QueryChanged event on the search page and on all other pages that provide searching on typing. On Keypress it will navigate to the search window and a query is executed on a service (1 sec delay) ... If it works at the end I will post here, but thanks for your quick answers ...